# Limit the duration of a TCP connection with iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp

Is it possible to limit the maximum **duration** of a TCP connection with `iptables`?

With `iptables` I can limit the number of *concurrent* TCP connections per IP address, by using `-m connlimit`, and I can also limit the number of *new* connections per IP address per time interval, by using `-m hashlimit`. I'm currently using these rules to get the desired effect:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 15/min --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name rtlimit -j DROP
```

However, is there a way to ensure that an "established" TCP connection will be **closed** after *at most* `n` seconds, in order to prevent "long-standing" connections? (regardless of still "active" or not)

I see people suggest:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 1/minute -j DROP
```

However, I don't think this really does what I want. To my understanding, above rule would drop all packets that are belonging to an "established" connection **and** that are coming in at a rate "faster" than one packet per minute. It doesn't close a connection after 1 minute elapsed, or does it?

Is there any way to actually accomplish this with `iptables`?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the iptables command itself to be used to set the limit?  Or is it enough if the limit applies to connections managed by iptables, but the limit itself is set with another command?

Comment: It would be okay, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now come up with a different "solution":

I wrote a small script that runs as a cronjob (once per minute) and that dumps all "established" connections into a file, by using the `ss` command and a bit of `grep` magic. I also keep the "old" file from the previous run. This way I can identify the connections that have "persisted" since the previous run, by concatenating the two files and then using `sort` plus `uniq -d`. These connections will then explicitly be closed, by using the `ss --kill` command. Seems to work for me.

(yes, this isn't an exact timeout, but probably "good enough" for my purpose)

---

List currently "established" connections:

```
ss -o state established
```

Get only "duplicate" lines:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq -d
```

Close connection, for example:

```
s --kill -o state established "( dst ${ip} and dport = ${port} )"
```

Comment: Please don't provide vague answers that make people *guess* how the solution could look like; instead provide a *working* answer that people can understand and comment on.

Comment: How is that answer vague? Using `ss` to "manually" investigate the established connections and using `ss --kill` to destroy "persistent" connections is the best "solution" that I have managed to come up with. If you know for a better way to accomplish this, e.g. with `iptables` rules, then please feel free to share it. Until then I think that sharing "my" solution should be fine...

Comment: Some more details on how I call `ss` command has been added.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: There are two issues with my answer.  1) I did not address the part of the question that states 'regardless of still "active" or not'; and 2) The question is about closing the socket at the endpoint(s) of the connection and not about removing the connection from the tracking of iptables (netfilter).
END UPDATE.

I see two options here:

## Option 1 - global

**Limit the idle timeout value of an established connection, for all connections by modifying the appropriate global netfilter variable.**

Verify the current default value with:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established
```

Modify the default value (for example, to 600 seconds) with:

```
echo 600 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established
```

## Option 2 - granular

**Limit the idle timeout value of an established connection, for specific connections, by setting up a timeout policy and using that policy with the iptables command.**

Setup a timeout policy with:

```
nfct add timeout nam1 inet tcp established 600
```

Apply that policy to iptables rules:

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -j CT --timeout nam1
iptables -I OUTPUT -t raw -p tcp -j CT --timeout nam1
```

You might need to install the nfct tool, which on debian / ubuntu, comes from the package with the same name (nfct).

## Additional info

`man iptables-extensions` shows some information on the CT target.

`man nfct` shows an example which is close to the information you requested.  (You may have issues using the timeout policy with a name of more than four characters in length.)

The conntrack tool can be useful for following what's going on at different events of the connection (e.g. `conntrack -E -p tcp`).

Comment: Thanks! This seemed like a great solution, but turns out to *not* work. After setting up a 30 seconds timeout, using the method outlined in the **nfct** manpage, I was able to actually observe a `[DESTROY]` message after 30 seconds in the output of `conntrack -E -p tcp` on "my" connection – only that this did **not** close the connection at all! With `ss` I can see the connection (socket) is still there (EASTAB). Indeed, the connection (LDAP session in this case) was still up and working as if nothing had happened. Any ideas? With `ss --kill` I can close the connection, and that *does* work.

Comment: Ah, I think I better understand your question now.  I've provided a way to lower a timeout for the iptables connection entries.  You're concern is not with iptables itself.  You want to have the socket connections into/out of your system have a limited lifetime.  We may be able to use iptables to make your socket connections stop working after the timeout (by adding a few more rules to what's already in this answer).  I'm not sure we'll be able to cleanly close those socket connections after the timeout.